# Prefetch query with relational conditions - Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I'm trying to make a request that prefetch all the data to reduce the amount of requests to my database. I'm using the `prefetch_related()` method and the `Prefetch` object class to tell what to load in the same request.

**Code:**

```
pairs_queryset = Pair.objects.filter(quote_id="2781", last_price__isnull=False) \
                 | Pair.objects.filter(quote_id="825", last_price__isnull=False) \
                 | Pair.objects.filter(quote_id="3408", last_price__isnull=False)

queryset = Portfolio.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('connections__wallets__currency__metadata__images'),
    Prefetch('connections__wallets__currency__base_pairs', queryset=pairs_queryset),
).get(id=portfolio_id)

data = Serializer(queryset).data
```

**Models:**

```
class Connection(models.Model):
    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, related_name='exchange', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    portfolios = models.ManyToManyField(Portfolio, related_name='connections')

    # ...

class Pair(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)  # CoinMarketCap id

    exchange = models.ForeignKey(Exchange, related_name='pairs', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # ...
```

I have multiple `base_pairs` in my database that have a relation on to an `Exchange`(see above).

**My issue**:
I would like to add a filter to the prefetch related objects that uses a value contained in the connection (i.e. `exchange_id`) of the prefetch like this:

```
connections__wallets__currency__base_pairs
     ^                               |
     |_______________________________|
          depends on the current 
    connection's exchange_id attribute
```

As `connections` is a set (multiple values), I want that the following: `connections__wallets__currency__base_pair` retrieve the `base_pairs` related to the `connection` currently fetched.

I read the documentation and couldn't find any solution. Using prefetch highly decreases the request time (~5s instead of ~3min).

Another way:

```
# get portfolio + prefetch connections (and other things...)
    portfolio = Portfolio.objects.prefetch_related(
        'connections__wallets__currency__metadata__images'
    ).get(id=portfolio_id)

    for connection in portfolio.connections.all():
        # build filter
        pairs_queryset = ExchangePair.objects.filter(
            exchange_id=connection.exchange_id,
            quote_id__in=["825", "2781", "3408", "4687"],
            last_price__isnull=False,
        )
        # prefetch for related connections
        prefetch_related_objects(
            [connection],
            Prefetch('wallets__currency__base_pairs', queryset=pairs_queryset),
        )
```

Here, Django is reusing cache from the previous connections queries of the loop. So it is very fast. However, the cached base_pairs are mixed in the results because Django forgets about the filter queryset I pass to the `Prefetch()` instance. It clearly seems to be a bug with Django. So I'm looking for another way to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if what you ask exactly is possible, but you may split the prefetch stage in three steps:

- prefetch the connections
- build a filter based on the attributes of the connections objects
- prefetch the data linked to the connections using `prefetch_related_objects` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.prefetch_related_objects

```
# get portfolio + prefetch connections (and other things...)
portfolio = Portfolio.objects.prefetch_related(
    'connections__wallets__currency__metadata__images'
).get(id=portfolio_id)

# build filter
pairs_queryset = Pair.objects.filter(
    quote_id__in=("2781","825","3408"),
    last_price__isnull=False,
    connection__zzz__in = set(_.zzz for _ in portfolio.connections.all())
)

# prefetch for related connections
prefetch_related_objects(
    portfolio.connections.all(),
    Prefetch('wallets__currency__base_pairs', queryset=pairs_queryset
)
data = Serializer(portfolio).data
```

Comment: Ok check your question edit suggestions and approve the last one. I modified the code and this one seems to work. I will make some tests before validating your answer. Thanks.

Comment: @PaulBénéteau your edits go into a review queue, which is moderated by users of sufficient reputation. The autor can approve them, but in your case two people rejected your proposal (including me). Your edit made too many changes to the post. Feel free to post your adapted solution as a new answer. You can pay "tribute" to the original answer by linking to it. Also please note that you could upvote this answer if it helped you solve your problem

Comment: @Nielk Fetched pairs must depend on the connection.exchange_id. So I did this `    for connection in portfolio.connections.all():
        pairs_queryset = ExchangePair.objects.filter(
            exchange_id=connection.exchange_id,
            quote_id__in=["825", "2781", "3408", "4687"],
            last_price__isnull=False,
        )
        prefetch_related_objects(
            [connection],
            Prefetch('wallets__currency__base_pairs', queryset=pairs_queryset)
        )`
But it only works 90% of the time for any reason I can't explain.

Comment: @PaulBénéteau 
First, how do you check that "it works" ? if you remove the filter on `exchange_id`, does it work ?
iterating over each connection is less efficient (= you will generate more queries).
Taking a step back, if you just want to fetch all the pairs related to your portfolio efficiently, maybe there are other strategies - that would depend on your dataset (cardinality in each table, how much the pairs are shared between different currencies, ...))

Comment: @Nielk It doesn't work when base_pairs are fetched from another exchange_id. The only thing I can do is remove cache by doing connection.refresh_from_db() at the beginning of each loop. Because Django is misusing the cache and mixes all base_pairs from the ones fetched before even if it's not compliant to the queryset=pairs_queryset filter...

Comment: @Nielk check my answer, it works like this but it's not very fast so it doesn't fully answer the question. You will probably get what I want to achieve though.